# Is there a way to get the version of typescript thats included in the monaco editor at runtime?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using the typescript worker that's included in the monaco editor. 
I would like to show the typescript version that it's using to the user.
Can I get the version at runtime?
I can see the version in the ts namespace in the js, but how to access it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that is not possible at the moment. There is already a [pull request](http://github.com/microsoft/monaco-typescript/pull/27) in the pipe, which will expose the TypeScript version as public API. Until this change is published, they recommend to manual hard-code a TS version variable and update it if you change your monaco editor version.

Comment: Now available: `monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptVersion`